# AWS 1 subdomain share with multiple AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Can I do the following task with AWS Route53 and AWS Application ELB?

I have a subdomain (test.example.com) Alias to a Application ELB which is secure by security group to have limited access by IP.

Now I would like to create another Application ELB but still Alias to subdomain (https://test.example.com)

The reason I need the second ELB is because I need to open up certain url (example: https://test.example.com/animals/cat.jpg) to the public but not other url. So by using the second ELB which allows me to set to public and control by a WAF which only accepts if uri contains /animals/cat.jpg).

Can this be done by pointing 2 ELB to the same subdomain (https://test.example.com)?

Edit: This 2 ELB needs to be pointed back to the same EC2 instance.

Comment: Why would you not simply configure WAF on the single balancer with appropriate rules to do what you want?

Comment: Hi Michael, just thought of that. I can actually do that and restrict IP based on the URI right? so only allow the uri to public but others to restricted IP only

Answer (score 0):

An Application Load Balancer can direct traffic to a different Target Group **based upon the path being accessed**.

For example, requests to `test.example.com` could go to one **Target Group**, while requests to `test.example.com/animals/` could go to another Target Group. The Target Group lists the destinations for requests, such as Amazon EC2 instances or AWS Lambda functions.

Therefore, you do not need to "add another ELB", you can simply [Use Path-Based Routing with Your Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html).

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your comment. However, the target group are all pointing to 1 single EC2 instance, hence path base routing won't work i guess? Plus I can't use the existing ELB as its only restricted to certain IP. I was thinking to use weighted-routing to point single domain to 2 ELB. Do you think that's ideal?

Comment: A Target Group includes a port number. Thus, the same Amazon EC2 instance can service two separate Target Groups if the apps respond on different ports. Frankly, if you only have one EC2 instance, why are you using a Load Balancer?

Comment: Business requirements + needed a domain name as there's a multiple application running inside the EC2 instance. Again, the issue here is that it is the same application on same port. 1 EC2 instance 1 application 1 port (80). Just need to expose some part of the application to public while the rest remains restricted.

Comment: You can associate a Domain Name with an IP address using an A-Record, without having to use a Load Balancer. First, assign an Elastic IP address to the instance, then use that IP address in the A-Record. A Load Balancer is only required to "spread the load" of requests to multiple destinations.

Comment: Using weighted-routing will not satisfy your requirement. It will send requests to different destinations _regardless_ of the URL. Thus, you will get approximately half of all requests failing. If you are saying that you are only running one application, then you should use the application to restrict what it is serving. Yes, you could use a WAF to restrict access, but that is rather excessive for your use-case.

Comment: Hi John, sorry but i left out another requirements, business requirements state that the EC2 instance cannot be exposed to public due to security requirements from client. Only can use NAT gateway for outgoing and bastion for ssh.

Comment: Also for weighted routing, If i set 2 ELB with same weighted, 1 with WAF and 1 without WAF, will it still affect the incoming route? or possible on WAF redirect to another ELB if the URI does not meets the requirements?

Comment: Weighted routing will send some requests to one destination and other requests to another destination, in a weighted but unpredictable manner. It should not be used as a way to serve traffic to two destinations with different content.

Comment: Thanks for that information. i think i'll try the easiest way is to use 1 ELB, apply WAF in front of it and filter based on IP and the uri. probably will use a a few set of rules.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use CloudFront.

You could put CloudFront distribution between Route53 and your ALBs if you want to use two of them.

Then using lambda@edge you would **inspect the incoming request**, and **direct to either first or second ALB**. This is enabled using:

- [Content-Based Dynamic Origin Selection - Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-content-based-routing-examples)

Since the lambda@edge seats between Route53 and your ALBs, you could implement **variety of rules** to direct incoming traffic to specific ALB. They can include IPs, paths, headers or anything else that is required and can be executed in a lambda function.

Comment: Hi, do you mean use Cloudfront to redirect the traffic to lambda@edge first? For example https://www.example.com will redirect me to cloudfront and then cloudfront will redirect to the lambda@edge before redirecting to the ALBs? But how doI limit the access where the certain URI (/animas/cat.jpg) can be accessed by public but others are not?

Comment: @DerekLee You would have to implement such logic in the lambda. But if you want to use one ALB, then can use to target groups. But SG will block access to both TGs. You can't make them to only block traffic to one TG and enable public access to other TG.